# Can I sync my Tomboy notes from Windows through Ubuntu One?

Tags: windows, sync, tomboy

I have setup my Ubuntu system to synchronize Tomboy notes with the Ubuntu One service. I'm now trying Tomboy on Windows and it would be great to have it sync with Ubuntu One.

However, while Tomboy for Ubuntu does expose a 'Ubuntu One' service for synchronization, version 1.2.0 of Tomboy for Windows does not. I can, however, use a "Tomboy Web" service.

Does Ubuntu One behave as a Tomboy Web service and how would I configure it to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I found in this [related question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+question/105946) on the Ubuntu One Answers service on Launchpad, all you need to do is using this as the server:

```
https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find the solution to a more detailed tutorial for Tomboy sync using Windows and Ubuntu on [this blog](http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/tomboy-sync-using-windows-and-ubuntu/):

> The first step, if you don’t have such an account, is to register on
>   Canonical’s Ubuntu One service. It gives you 5GB free storage to sync
>   files, contacts and notes on all your Ubuntu machines. It’s meant to
>   support Windows OS soon enough.
>
> The second step is to install Tomboy on the Windows machine. To
>   install Tomboy on Windows, you need .NET framework and gtk-sharp
>   installed before you can install Tomboy:
>
> - [Get the .NET runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d0e5dea7-ac26-4ad7-b68c-fe5076bba986&DisplayLang=pt-br)
> - [Get the GTK# runtime](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html)
> - [Get Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/download.html)
>
> After installing Tomboy, start the application. It automatically sets up an icon on the
>   system tray. Press the right mouse button on it and choose
>   “Preferences”.
>
> Go to the “Synchronization” tab and select the “Tomboy Web” service. On the server insert the following address: https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/
>
> Choose the interval between synchronizations. Press “Save” and you’re
>   all done on the Windows box. For the Ubuntu machine, there is [this
>   detailed tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Notes) on notes configuration on the Ubuntu One wiki pages.

Answer (score 1):

I found I had the same issue as described here... I did add "https://one.ubuntu.com/notes" under preferences->synchronization in Tomboy (running under XP). However, wouldn't connect to the server.

Solution was to ensure Tomboy is added to the exceptions in Windows Firewall. I set up this exception, restarted Tomboy and presto, it allowed me to set up the sync service with Ubuntu One.